# window.reload() after subscribe result using async/await

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await

I need to reload the browser after finish the forEach loop of the functionality on my Observable.

I am using Angular 7, I am doing a forEach iteration and I want to reload the brownser at the end of the loop.

```
async validateMetric(metrics: Metric[]) {
   metrics.forEach(metric => {
    this.metricsService.editMetric(metric)
     .subscribe(metricUpdated => {
       return metricUpdated;
      })
    });
    await location.reload();
  }
```

Expected behaviour: Reload the page after the forEach loop
Actual behaviour: It reloads the browser before iterate the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of async/await my suggestion here would be to solve this is by using rxjs 'forkJoin'.

```
validateMetric(metrics: Metric[]) {

  let metricObservables[]: Observable[];

  metrics.forEach(metric => {
     metricObservables.push(this.metricsService.editMetric(metric);
  });

  forkJoin(metricObservables).subscribe(result => { location.reload(); })

}
```

to understand more about forkJoin
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this:

```
async validateMetric(metrics: Metric[]) {
  metrics.forEach(metric => {
    await this.metricsService.editMetric(metric)
      .subscribe(metricUpdated => {
        return metricUpdated;
      })
  });
  location.reload();
}
```